# Verifying Googlebot in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-crawlers

I am looking to implement [First Click Free](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/first-click-free-for-web-search.html) in my rails application. Google has this information on how to verify a if a googlebot is viewing your site [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553).

I have been searching to see if there is anything existing for Rails to do this but I have been unable to find anything. So firstly, does anyone know of anything? If not, could anyone point me in the right direction of how to go about implementing what they have suggested in that page about how to verify?

Also, in that solution, it has to do a lookup every time to try and detect google, that seems like its going to be a big performance hit if I have to do it every page load? I could cache the IP if it has been verified in the past but Google have stated that their IP's change so at some point it may no longer belong to them. Although it probably doesn't happen regularly so it may not be that big of an issue.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Check out the browser gem: https://github.com/fnando/browser

What I'd do is use the

```
browser.bot?
```

method to check if your site is being accessed by a bot or not. If you care about the Googlebot specifically, you could check if

```
browser.name
```

includes googlebot. Keep in mind that this gem just checks the user agent sent by the client's browser, which could of course be spoofed. Sounds like that isn't a huge concern for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did consider this as an option, and may still give it a go, although as you say, someone could just spoof the user agent and then get all the content for free. I think this is why google recommend verifying the IP in that article so you can be sure but it sounds like quite a large overhead to me.

Comment: That makes sense. Of course, it would be pretty easy to spoof an ip by just using a proxy server. If you're worried about spoofing, ultimately having users create actual accounts with verified emails would probably be the best way to go.

Comment: @apod in that case bots wont be able to index the paid content, right?

Answer (score 0):

I've built a Ruby gem for that recently, it's called "[legitbot](https://github.com/alaz/legitbot)".

You may learn if a Web request comes from a supported bot using

```
bot = Legitbot.bot(userAgent, ip)
```

"legitbot" does this looking into `User-agent` and searching for a bot signature, i.e. how bots identify themselves. This doesn't guarantee that the Web request IP really comes from e.g. Googlebot. To make sure it is, call

```
bot.detected_as # => "Google"
bot.valid? # => true
bot.fake? # => false
```

Supported bots are Googlebot, Yandex bots, Bing, Baidu, DuckDuckGo.