# Web crawlers overloading site

Tags: nginx, fail2ban

We have a problem with a number of our sites where Yahoo, Google, Yandex, Bing Ahrefs and others all index the site at the same time which kills the website.

I've configured fail2ban to block the source IPs, but these are forever changing so not ideal.  I have also tried using robots.txt but this makes little difference.

We have tried putting the site behind cloudflare, but again this makes little difference and all we can do is block the source IPs.

What else can I do?

Currently we're monitoring the site with Nagios, which restarts nginx when the site becomes un-responsive, but this seems far from ideal.

Ubuntu server running nginx

Robots.txt file is here:-

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Posting here in case there is anything that I can get our developers to try.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that Stack Overflow is the right place to ask this. Regardless, please post your /robots.txt here.

Comment: a) I think server fault might be the more fitting site on stack exchange b) are you sure the robots.txt is in the right directory? at least google, yahoo and bing do respect it. google has a test tool for the robots.txt somewhere in its webmaster tools

Answer (score 2):

An easy approach is to rate limit them based on `User-Agent` header in their requests. Schematically this looks like the following.

At `http` level in Nginx configuration:

```
map $http_user_agent $bot_ua {
  default '';

  "~*Googlebot|Bing" Y;
}

limit_req_zone $bot_ua zone=bot:1m rate=1r/s;
```

This will make sure that all requests with `Googlebot` or `Bing` in `User-Agent` will be rate limited to 1 request per second. Note that rate limiting will be "global" (vs. per-IP), i.e. all of the bots will wait in a single queue to access the web site. The configuration can be easily modified to rate limit on per-IP basis or to white list some user agents.

At `server` or `location` level:

```
limit_req zone=bot burst=5;
```

Which means a "burst" of 5 requests is possible. You may drop this option if you want.

- [Nginx rate limit documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html)
- [Nginx map documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html)

Nginx will issue HTTP status code 429 when a request is rate limited. "Sane" web crawlers detect this and slow down scanning the site.

---

Though I should say this whole problem is much more complicated. There are a lot of malicious requests pretending they are from Google, Twitter, FB, etc. coming from various scanners and crawlers (e.g. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201654/verifying-googlebot-in-rails/41238087#41238087)) and they respect neither `robots.txt` nor 429. Sometimes they are quite smart and have `User-Agents` mimicing browsers. In this case the approach above will not help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your *robots.txt* should have worked. And note that not all crawlers respect robots.txt.

*robots.txt* is case-sensitive, and it needs to be world-readable at www.yourdomain.com/robots.txt.

See what happens when you add `Crawl-delay: 10`.